# Why does using the move variant of std::vector::push_back invoke the moved item's copy constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, move

Here's some code that won't compile because push_back is trying to call the copy constructor in MoveOnlyClass, which is deleted:

```
class MoveOnlyClass
{
public:
    MoveOnlyClass() {};
    MoveOnlyClass& operator=(const MoveOnlyClass& other) = delete;
    MoveOnlyClass(const MoveOnlyClass& other) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MoveOnlyClass> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::move(MoveOnlyClass()));
}
```

Why does this happen? Surely the only thing the vector should be calling is the move constructor. What would be the correct way to move an object into a vector?

Comment: The class doesn't have a move constructor

Comment: btw it would be good to include the error message. it usually gives a hint what is wrong

Comment: @user463035818 True. I didn't think about that when writing the example.

Comment: @tkausl Ah, right. So it just falls back on the copy constructor and fails because it doesn't exist?

Comment: Does anyone know what the downvotes are for? Is it just because it's an obvious answer or is it because I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: @Tharwen SE has a toxicity problem. Your questions deals with a relatively trivial (if understandable) mistake, so more elitist users will sometimes react funny to these kinds of questions. Not much you can do about it, unfortunately.

Comment: my downvote was for no research. Instead of assuming that there was a move constructor you could have added it via `=default` or it took me 2 minutes to check under what conditions the compiler generates the move constructor. Nothing personal, one downvote wont hurt anybody, I am sure others will find it upvotable, I stand by my decision ;)

Comment: @user463035818 I thought I was dealing with an unrelated problem to the move constructor being deleted, so I didn't think to check that

Comment: It might be worth adding: if the class has both a copy constructor and a move constructor, but the move constructor is not declared `noexcept`, then `std::vector` will use the copy constructor.  (But defaulted move constructors are automatically `noexcept` if appropriate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the copy constructor/copy assignment function also implicitly deletes the move-constructor/move assignment function. If you intend to make an object movable but not copyable, you also need to `default` the move-constructor.

```
class MoveOnlyClass
{
public:
    MoveOnlyClass() {};
    MoveOnlyClass& operator=(const MoveOnlyClass& other) = delete;
    MoveOnlyClass(const MoveOnlyClass& other) = delete;
    MoveOnlyClass& operator=(MoveOnlyClass&& other) = default;
    MoveOnlyClass(MoveOnlyClass&& other) = default;
};

//Will now compile as you expect
int main()
{
    std::vector<MoveOnlyClass> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::move(MoveOnlyClass()));
}
```

Also, `std::move(T())` is redundant; constructing an object in-place like that will already make it an R-value, and using `std::move` when you don't need to may prevent some kinds of compiler optimizations (like Copy Ellision).

Comment: @JeJo `std::vector` can still resize itself if its objects are non-copyable. It's only non-movable objects where this would be an issue.

Comment: I'd recommend `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`

Comment: The `<type_traits>` for `std::is_move_assignable` and `std::is_move_constructible` may be of interest, to programmatically verify the target class object has the desired characteristics.

Comment: It's a good habit to mark the move constructor and move assignment operator `noexcept` if they are.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Xirema seals the deal about the problem in the code, and explains why that is the case.

I just want to back it up with the appropriate excerpts from the language spec, to make things official. So from [[class.copy.ctor¶8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#8):

> (8) If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as defaulted **if and only if**
>
> - (8.1) **X does not have a user-declared copy constructor**,

For this we should add that declaring as deleted is still declaring. Hence according to this we don't get the *implicitly declared move constructor* in your case, as we already have a *user-declared copy constructor*.

Further, under [[dcl.fct.def.delete¶3]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.delete#3.sentence-3):

> **One can make a class uncopyable,** i.e., move-only, by using deleted
> definitions of the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, **and
> then providing defaulted definitions of the move constructor and move
> assignment operator.**